# Eclipse - Clicking in XML content deletes/rearranges it?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-xml

I'm working in Eclipse and in my Android app, if I click around inside my XML file, it randomly re arranges the text and even deletes some of it! Has this happened to any of you, and if so, what is going on here?!

Comment: Most likely a bug with their eclipse plugin.

Comment: I haven't faced this issue. What version of Eclipse/ADT are you on? What OS? Also, have you tried playing around with the settings in Preferences -> Android -> Editors ??

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.7 with the Android ADT Plugin on Windows 7 Home Premium. There aren't any options for it in Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because there is some error in eclipse. Usually, just save it where you are and just reopen it. Yes, I do agree that you will lose the ability to undo once you close the file and reopen it :( but what can you do. hopefully, they fix i :)